# JS Display none with PHP foreach only working with first elemnt

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm bringing articles from a database with `ORDER BY RAND()` with a PHP foreach cycle:

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
    <div class="post" id="post">
        <article>
            <div class="post-head">
                <a href="<?php echo ROUTE; ?>/profile.php/<?php echo $post['user_id']; ?>">
                    <img class="post-pfp" src="<?php echo ROUTE; ?>/users_pics/<?php echo ($post['profile_pic']); ?>">
                </a>

                <h1>
                    <a class="links-3" href="<?php echo ROUTE; ?>/profile.php?user=<?php echo $post['user_id']; ?>"><?php echo $post['post_by']; ?></a>
                </h1>
                
                <p class="post-date"><?php echo get_date($post['date']); ?></p>

                <div class="x_hover" onclick="hide_post()">
                    <img src="<?php echo ROUTE; ?>/icons/cross.svg">
                </div>

                <hr id="post-hr">

                <br>

                <a href="<?php echo ROUTE; ?>/post.php?p=<?php echo $post['ID']; ?>">
                    <p class="post-content"><?php echo $post['content']; ?></p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can see, the div with the class `x_hover` has an onclick attribute:

```
<div class="x_hover" onclick="hide_post()">
    <img src="<?php echo ROUTE; ?>/icons/cross.svg">
</div>
```

What the `hide_post()` function does is this:

```
var post = document.getElementsByClassName("post");

function hide_post(){
    if (post[0].style.display = "block") {
        post[0].style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

I'm new to JS so I have some issues as well.

We are declaring that var `post` is equal to all the elements with the class name "post", such as the HTML code I added at the beginning, has the class `post`:

`<div class="post" id="post">`

This div has the `display: block;` attribute. However, when I run all this code, It only turns into `display: none` the first element that brings us from the database, it doesn't works with the rest of them...

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

IDs must be unique and since you have named all of the `post` only the first one will ever been "seen". Make the IDs unique, change your `hide_post` function to accept a ID name to hide, and add the unique ID to your `onclick` calls.

Change

```
<div class="post" id="post">
```

to something like

```
<div class="post" id="post<?php echo $post['ID']; ?>">
```

Then change

```
<div class="x_hover" onclick="hide_post()">
```

to

```
<div class="x_hover" onclick="hide_post('post<?php echo $post['ID']; ?>')">
```

Finally, modify your `hide_post` function to accept the name of the ID to show or hide.

```
function hide_post(idToHide){
    if (idToHide.style.display = "block") {
        idToHide.style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to JS... What do you mean with IDs and how do I change my function to accept ID names? I'm new to JS.

Comment: I modified my answer which should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ok but then the var `post` would be equal to what? My code is this:
`var post = document.querySelectorAll('.post');

function hide_post(idToHide){
    if (idToHide.style.display = "block") {
        idToHide.style.display = "none"
    }
}` Tha var post would be equal to something else? Help please

Answer (score 0):

When you use `getElementsByClassName` it returns an `HTMLCollection`. You should iterate elements and hide all of them if it's what you intent to. Right now you are just hiding 0th element of this collection.

```js
var posts = document.getElementsByClassName("post");

for (let post of posts) {
    if (post.style.display = "block") {
        post.style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

If you intent to hide a single post you give unique ids to divs, and call `hide_post` with id of that post. Also you should use `getElementById` for that. Notice that it's not plural. Function should be like this:

```js
function hide_post(postId){
    var post = document.getElementById(postId);

    if (post.style.display = "block") {
        post.style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

Comment: I did exactly that, but now when I check the terminal, it marks this:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
 at hide_post at HTMLDivElement.onclick` What can I do? I also assigned unique ID's from the database to divs...

Comment: Are you calling function with id like Dave said? `<div class="x_hover" onclick="hide_post('post<?php echo $post['ID']; ?>')">`. What's out of `console.log(postId)` in js function?

Comment: Oh now it IS working! I wasn't setting the class name correctly on `document.getElementsByClassName("post");`

Answer (score 0):

A more cleaner way of doing this would be.

```
function hide_post() {
document.querySelectorAll('.post').forEach(v => {
if(v.style.display == block) v.style.display = none; }); }
```

Comment: It searches for all element with class post and loop through each element and make them display none if the display style is block

Comment: So as I understand it should go like this:
‘function hide_post() {
document.querySelectorAll('.post').forEach(v => {
if(v.style.display == block) v.style.display = none; }); }
‘ It should go like that? I did not understood clearly...

Comment: yes sorry i forgot to put function keywork in front

Comment: I did this:
`function hide_post() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.post').forEach(v => {if(v.style.display ==" block") v.style.display = "none"; });
}`

Comment: Well, when I click it, it doesn't work, it doesn't make anything :/
My code is the same, and in the terminal, it doesn't give any error or something...
What is going on?